# jQuery Snap to Grid Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've read somewhere that you can snap the object after it has been moved, but how can I incorporate that code into my own?  I found this code:

```
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    t = parseInt($(this).css(top);
    l = parseInt($(this).css(left);
    $(this).css(top , t - t % 30);
    $(this).css(left, l - l % 30);
  }
```

But where would I put that in this:?

```
$('.box').draggable({grid: [10,10]}).resizable({grid: 50});
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm new to this, I honestly have no idea how, or what that is... :( sorry to everybody!

Comment: No worries! Make sure to check out the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [snap and snapTolerance](http://ui-dev.jquery.com/demos/draggable/#snap-to) options for draggables?

Comment: I have, actually, thanks for posting!  What I'm doing is having a user be able to right-click anywhere, and a div with a class of 'box' appears where they right-clicked.  However, the snap only snaps relative to where the original click was.  I need it to snap to a sort of 'global' grid, shared by all.